# Reverse and swap case of the string

Tags: python, case, reverse, swap

What's the most efficient way to reverse the string and swap the case? For example, if my input string is:

```
input_string = "Hello Python World"
```

I want the content of the string to be:

```
output_string = "DLROw NOHTYp OLLEh"
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Wrong question ask again. What have you tried? What isn't working?

Answer (score 3):

You may swap the case using [**`str.swapcase()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.swapcase) on the reversed string (or vice-versa) as:

```
input_string = "Hello Python World"

output_string = input_string[::-1].swapcase()
#        to reverse the string ^                 

# OR, input_string.swapcase()[::-1]
```

where `output_string` will hold:

```
>>> output_string
'DLROw NOHTYp OLLEh'
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
''.join([c.lower() if c.isupper() else c.upper() for c in my_string][::-1])
```